# Bug In Using Del To Remove Elements In 2D List

Tags: python

So this is part of a bigger dataset but I simplified it here. Say You have the following code. What I'm trying to do is extract the sub arrays, based on what the middle element is (that's what dataStore is for). Side note, I know about list mutability and that when I do del row[1], I permanently affect data

```
dataStore = []
data = [[1,3,7], [1,0,1],[2,0,2],[9,0,9], [3,1,9]]
print(data)
for index in range(0, 5):
    temp = []
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == index:
            del row[1]
            temp.append(row)
            del data[ data.index(row)]
    dataStore.append(temp)
```

The output is:
`Data:      [[2, 0, 2]]
             DataStore: [[[1, 1], [9, 9]], [[3, 9]], [], [[1, 7]], []]`

Now Data is supposed to be empty after I'm done, and the bug here is that (2,0,2) that doesn't get deleted because it's back to back with something that just got deleted. How do you get around this?

How I go about things: I feel like the reason is because when you do `del data[ data.index(row)]`it moves everything up by one but row is still iterating forward. So I was thinking of a solution of a 2nd mirror list but I couldn't figure out the syntax for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you NEED the `data` array to be empty when you're done? I'm not sure, but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
data = [[1,3,7], [1,0,1], [2,0,2], [9,0,9], [3,1,9]]
dataStore = []
for index in range(0, 5):
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == index:
            dataStore.append([row[0], row[2]])
print(dataStore)
```

Everything is just stored in the new `dataStore` array instead of deleting the current `data` array. If you're iterating over an array, you never want to modify it while doing so. The output should be: `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [9, 9], [3, 9], [1, 7]]`

Note that this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but you won't notice unless you're working with very large sets of data.

Comment: This is the method I ended up choosing, except I ended up splicing the row twice since the original issue would have variable size

Answer (score 0):

Your feelings are correct. As a rule of thumb you should never modify a list if you are iterating through it.

If I understand your problem correctly, the end result of your code is that you should have an array in DataStore that is every element in data sorted by the middle element with the middle element removed. If that is the case then I would try something a little simpler like so:

```
dataStore = [[x[0],x[1]] for x in sorted(data,key=lambda i: i[1])]
del data
```